# What is the "official" place for community support for the Mere Mortals .NET framework?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

My team is using the [Mere Mortals .NET framework from Oak Leaf](http://oakleafsd.com/FrameSet.htm?product=mmnet).  Being used to working with primarily open source software, I found it excruciatingly painful to find ANY community support for MM.NET.  When I asked if there was any, the only place I was given to look for support was [Universal Thread](http://universalthread.com/), which is a site which requires a membership for search on archived questions.  It seems like a third party, pay-for site should not be the primary source of support for anything like this, especially MM.NET which costs [$700 per developer](http://oakleafsd.com/FrameSet.htm?product=mmnet).  It doesn't seem to me like an entire community around MM.NET would choose to all pay on top of the license just to use a forum.  If not Universal Thread, then what is the "official" place to find support for the Mere Mortals .NET framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found in the MM.NET Developer's Guide that Universal Thread is the "official" community support site.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest investigating this stuff before you invest, the only problem worse than trying to get support now, is trying to get support in a few years time.

Having said that, if they're taking money for the product they should be giving you direct support via email or otherwise, you shouldn't have to find "community support".

Comment: +1 For investigating before you invest.  Unfortunately, I came onto the project with many of the decisions already made and far enough along that it doesn't make sense to turn back, so I'm trying to make the best of things.